# jest return ERROR: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: "module"' (21:0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a demo repo setup already https://github.com/adamchenwei/jest-playground

You should be able to reproduce the same error by run `npm run test`

[image]

Not really sure what is causing it, any idea how to debugging further on this? I already minimize the code in the component, but for some reason, jest still failing with that little bit code. I haven't even be able to get into the problem with image loading yet lol

Comment: what transpiler and bundler are you using?

Comment: @Sag1v if you check the demo repo, you should see `webpack` if that's what you are asking

Comment: strange it doesn't show it as a dependency in your `package.json`

Comment: hum.... not sure why but its webpack for sure

Comment: aww was it built with create react app?

Comment: yep, indeed @Sag1v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159426/discussion-between-ezeewei-and-sag1v).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. Actually, it had wrong babel setup. That's why its throwing that error!

I fixed the issue in this commit, check it out! adding the missing babel config in package.json and updated babel deps. Took me a while to figure it out! Hope someone finds it helpful!

https://github.com/adamchenwei/jest-playground/commit/ed2d635b779fab52876069f53584aaa48a9c66a7

Enjoy!

Comment: @swyx nice glad it helped! a vote up can give me a great sense of achievement haha